# BluetoothSocket.connect() getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

currently when I try to execute `BluetoothSocket.connect()`, it always ends of with the following exception:

```
01-26 13:54:07.501  17483-17744/asdev.com.envirable W/BluetoothAdapter﹕ getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
```

My connect device code:

```
  public ProgressDialog pairDia;
private BluetoothSocket sock;
private int whyConn = -1;
private static final UUID CONNUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
public void connectDevice(BluetoothDevice bd){
       try{
           if(whyConn == CONN_USER)
              pairDia = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Connecting...", true, true);
           else if(whyConn == CONN_AUTO)
               pairDia = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Auto connecting...", true, true);
           pairDia.setCancelable(true);
           pairDia.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
               public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    if(conner != null && !conner.isCancelled()){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.getContext(), "#onCancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        conner.cancel(true);
                    }
               }
           });
           if(sock != null)
               if(sock.isConnected())
                    Toast.makeText(this, "#connectDevice ALREADY CONNED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
           if(sharedPreferences.contains(getString(R.string.pref_socket_security))){
                if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_socket_security), false)){
                    //secure
                    sock = bd.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(CONNUUID);
                }else{
                    //insecure
                    sock = bd.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(CONNUUID);
                }
           }else{
               sock = bd.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(CONNUUID);
           }
           Toast.makeText(this, "#sock = createSocket", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           conner = new SocketConnector(this);
           conner.execute("");
           //start async activity
           //connected
       }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           this.finish();
       }
}
```

The socket connector:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
         m.getSocket().connect();
         conn = true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        conn = false;
        //not conn
        Toast.makeText(m, "Unable to connect!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    m.pairDia.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(m, "Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return "connected!";
}

private boolean conn = false;
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    if(!conn){
        Toast.makeText(m, "Unable to connect!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(m, "Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i = new Intent(m, VisualizerActivity.class);
        m.startActivityForResult(i, MainActivity.VIS_REQ);
    }
}
```

This had just recently started happening, and it seemed to work before. Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:** Restarting the phone seemed to fix it for now but does anyone know why this happens?